# classic asp TSQL no rowset returned

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp-classic

I have some TSQL used in classic asp like this:

```
Declare @tbl TABLE(some columns)
Declare @somevarables

Declare myCur CURSOR
For
    Select something From my_table
Open myCur

Fetch Next From myCur Inti somevarables
While (@@Fetch_Status<>-1)
  Begin
    some processimg
    ......
    Insert Into @tbl(...)
    Values(...)

    Fetch Next From myCur Inti somevarables
  End
Deallocate myCur

Select * From @tbl
```

The scripts worked well in SQL Query Analyzer. However, when I run it in an ASP page, there's no rowset returned, nor error message.

Who can tell me why?

Thanks!

Comment: You need `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to stop your inserts rows affected being counted as closed recordsets.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a cursor? Processing like this is really inefficient, could you not use `INSERT INTO @tbl (...) SELECT ... FROM my_table`?

Comment: TSQL should not be executed from application directly, put it into stored procedure and call stored procedure from your application.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky It actually doesn't matter if you use a `ADODB.Command` to process it as `adCmdText`. But in this case I would agree it would be better in a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart! That's beautifull!

Comment: @user3349078 Glad that helped will leave an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @Lankymart:`SET NOCOUNt ON` works well. Actually, each item in my_table has some multi-itemed details in another table - say my_detail. I want to summarize those details. I tried to build a function do the summarization. Unfortunately, this involved dynamic sql, which connot be execute in function. Usually I do it in two steps in ASP: first get rowset from my_table. second loop through rowset, for each row get detail rowset from my_detail. then sommurize them. Any comments or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're inserting multiple times and each time your rows affected count will generate a closed recordset.

Simple fix is to make sure in your T-SQL you first `SET NOCOUNT ON;`, this will stop the row counts and the only recordset returned will be your end `SELECT`.